# Directshow video capture filter IAMBufferNegotiation::GetAllocatorProperties returns E_FAIL

Tags: c, video-capture, directshow

I am trying to inspect the allocator properties of Audio/Video capture filters. I use `IAMBufferNegotiation::GetAllocatorProperties` and Capture filter's output pin is connected. It works fine with Audio Capture filter but not Video Capture filter.

with Audio capture filter:
HRESULT: S_OK
cBuffers: 4
cbBuffer: 88200
cbAlign: 1
cbPrefix: 0

with Video capture filter:
HRESULT: E_FAIL (0x80004005), which is not specified by the Microsoft documentation. they said possible values are: S_OK, E_POINTER, VFW_E_NOT_CONNECTED (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/nf-strmif-iambuffernegotiation-getallocatorproperties)

so Why it it? why I can get `IAMBufferNegotiation` interface of Video Capture filter and even call `SuggestAllocatorProperties` successfully (return S_OK) but fail with `GetAllocatorProperties`?

Comment: Unlike audio, video is delivered frame by frame anyway. What exactly you are trying to reach with this interface and tweaking?

Comment: @RomanR. for Audio, I can get buffer size through this interface and set for my custom source. `CMediaType::GetSampleSize` only gets size of a small audio sample not entire audio buffer. but if video is always delivered frame by frame, so `CMediaType::GetSampleSize` looks ok to get video buffer size? isn't that weird when cannot get the allocator properties of video capture filter?

Comment: So, what is the goal? What are you trying to query or change? Video capture filter connection can work out without all this.

Comment: @RomanR. I am writing video livestreaming app. I collect samples/buffers from live source such as video capture filter and pass them to another client. the client will re-render those buffers using Custom Source. and the implement of custom source requires determining the buffer size (`DecideBufferSize`). so that's why I want to get the buffer size of audio/video buffers.

Answer (score 1):

[`IAMBufferNegotiation::SuggestAllocatorProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/nf-strmif-iambuffernegotiation-suggestallocatorproperties) method is not the right way to negotiate buffer size for video.

With audio this interface is used to apply preferences for audio buffering, and in the case of video frame size is rather determined by pin connection media type (such as `DecideBufferSize` call [e.g. here](https://github.com/roman380/Windows-classic-samples/blob/8ee7e4d65614de270916cd881fa00fb0d0cb6b00/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/filters/pushsource/PushSourceBitmap.cpp#L231)).

With video `IAMBufferNegotiation` can be used to instruct the video capture filter to allocate more or less buffers for data exchange, but not the buffer (frame) size. Then the interface is typically used before pin is connected, and so there is no media type yet so the buffer size might not be available upfront, hence failure in `GetAllocatorProperties`.

> ... I want to get the buffer size of audio/video buffers

Audio:

Implementers of `IAMBufferNegotiation` offer this interface to let application select buffer latency, and specifically in what chunks the filter would provide audio.

Video:

Use of this interface is not really practical. In certain cases filter implementers might let application to override number of video buffers in allocator. Filters producing video are not expecting buffer size to be provided via this interface. `GetAllocatorProperties` is intended to provide the application a method to re-check if the suggestion was honored, so checking buffer size using this interface is not the reliable way to query for buffer size.

How to check buffer size?

- upstream filters normally don't need to check because they are responsible  to configure the actual allocator, so they do know the size;
- downstream fitler check this when receiving allocator from upstream connection, and comoparing against connection media type;
- applciations are not supposed to access the interface because it's related to internal filter-to-filter communication, if you need this data you always
  have better ways for the query.

Comment: but I said in my question: I call `GetAllocatorProperties` **after** Capture filter's output pin is connected. and it succeeds with audio capture filter but fails with video capture.

Comment: or maybe my device or webcam has problems. anyway I haven't tested on other devices yet.

Comment: You should not be relying on this interface in first place, it is not designed to inform on buffer size. The fact that it works for audio does not make a valid point: video is not audio and the interface is still optional.

Comment: yes, I think `IAMBufferNegotiation` is appropriate for audio not video.

Comment: finally, I got the buffer size for video capture. Thanks to your suggestion, I use `IMemInputPin` of downstream filter `SmartPinTee` to `GetAllocator` and then `IMemAllocator::GetProperties` succeeded.